# Is there any way to persist files for a web application using Amazon AWS without a full VM?

Tags: asp.net, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I would like to migrate an web application to Amazon AWS.

The application stores and retrieves small persistent data from a `content/` directory. I tried Amazon Elastic Beanstalk to deploy the application however it does not allow persistent storage.

The Amazon solution to use beanstalk is to create a s3 bucket and use Amazon APIs to store data.

I rather not modify our code and create total dependency to Amazon Services.

Is there any way to migrate my application **without** change the code to amazon services. I would like to do not create a full VM just to run the application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to persist data in AWS is [Elastic File System](https://aws.amazon.com/efs/), you can mount your folder "content".

Answer (score 1):

1. Start by creating a persistent volume with the present
2. When an instance is created manually or auto launched attach the persistent volume to the instance using the user data
3. Also, make sure to provide the folder name to which the volume data needs to be loaded